# Compose multiplatform: store and load svg icons

Tags: android, ios, kotlin, compose-multiplatform

Is there a way to store and load svg icons locally in Compose multiplatform?
I am looking for a multiplatform solution that will work on two platforms: android and ios.

Thanks in advance